# How do I add a pipeline to a REQ-REP in ZeroMQ?

Tags: zeromq, zero

I am experimenting with ZeroMQ where I want to create a server that does :

REQ-PIPELINE-REPLY

I want to sequentially receives data query requests, push it through a inproc pipeline to parallelise the data query and the sink merges the data back. After the sink merges the data together, the sink sends the merged data as the reply back to the request.

Is this possible? How would it look? I am not sure if the push/pull will preserve client's address for the REP socket to send back to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that each client has only a single request out at any one time.

> Is this possible?

Yes, but with different socket types.

> How would it look?

(in C)

What you may like to do is shift from a ZMQ_REP socket on the external server socket to a ZMQ_ROUTER socket. The Router/Dealer sockets have identities which can allow you to have multiple requests in your pipeline and still respond correctly to each.

The Asynchronous Client/Server Pattern:
http://zguide.zeromq.org/php:chapter3#The-Asynchronous-Client-Server-Pattern

The only hitch in this is that you will need to manage the multiple parts of the ZMQ message. The first part is the identity. Second is null. Third is the data. As long as you REPLY in the same order as the REQUEST the identity will guide your response's data to the correct client. I wrapped my requests in a struct:

```
struct msg {
   zmq_msg * identity;
   zmq_msg * nullMsg;
   zmq_msg * data;
};
```

Make sure to use [zmq_msg_more](http://api.zeromq.org/4-0:zmq-msg-more) when receiving messages and set the more flag when sending correctly.

> I am not sure if the push/pull will preserve client's address for the
>   REP socket to send back to.

You are correct. A push pull pattern would not allow for specifying of the return address between multiple clients.